# Get OpenWeatherMap JSON data to view

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, openweathermap

I am trying to use OpenWeatherMap to provide a weather feed to an MVC built website.
Model as follows:

```
{
    public class OpenWeatherMap
    {
        public List<Data> list;
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public Main main { get; set; }
        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public Rain rain { get; set; }
        public string dt_txt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }
        public double temp_min { get; set; }
        public double temp_max { get; set; }
        public double pressure { get; set; }
        public double sea_level { get; set; }
        public double grnd_level { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public double temp_kf { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string main { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clouds
    {
        public int all { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wind
    {
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public double deg { get; set; }
    }   
    public class Rain
    { 
        public double rain { get; set; }                  
    }

    public class Sys
    {
        public string pod { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller as follows:

```
    public OpenWeatherMap GetLocalWeather()
    {

        string apiUrl = BaseURL + "id=" + CityID + "&appid=" + AppID + "&units=metric";

        string result = RequestHandler.Process(apiUrl);

        OpenWeatherMap lWeather = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<OpenWeatherMap>(result);


        return lWeather;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        OpenWeatherMap localWeather = GetLocalWeather();

      return View();
     }
```

I  have two questions:

1. What is the best method to proceed to pass the data to the View and have noticed that now and again the JSON data will omit items e.g. the rainfall data today disappeared.
2. What is the best method to cover such an event?

Comment: I would build a view model and pass that to the view and in the model you can handle if a value is not set what to display in the view for the case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Comment: @DerekHackett Thank you for your reply. I have tried default settings in the Model such as:- public class Rain
    { 
        public double rain { get; set; } 
        
        public Rain()
        {
            this.rain = 0.0;
        }
    } but the json data returned contains no reference to Rain therefore I am getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Other than commenting out the class Rain is there anything else I can do.

Comment: This is what I would do. Does this work for you? public class Weather
{
    private double _rain;
    public double Rain { get {
            if (_rain != null)
                return _rain;
            else return 0.0;
    } set { _rain = value; } }
}

Comment: Derek Hackett Thank you so much, it has cleared the fault and now all I have to do is wait until it starts returning the rain data to see it working. Again, many thanks for your time.

Comment: I will add it as the answer if you want to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix your issue.

```
public class Weather { 
    private double _rain; 
    public double Rain { 
        get { if     (_rain != null) return _rain; else return 0.0; } 
        set { _rain = value; } } 
}
```